# Create and synchronize simple database in Android application

Tags: android, database, synchronization

I am going to write an Android application that should use database to store categories and items.

I have to store this data in some cloud (to restore it when user install this application on the second device).

What is the painless way to do it ? Should I use `SQLite` or is it possible to do it in easier way ?

In what way should I sync it with cloud ? Any Google solutions are available ?

Comment: This is a theoretical question for now. I am trying to concider the best way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google has backup service for this. For details please see the URL below:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html